# Loading Perl modules into memory for Nginx, to make faster?

Tags: perl, nginx

I'm trying to speed up my Perl scripts on an **nginx** server. In a test script, if I comment out the "use" requests for 3 **.pm** files (all of which do their own stuff) ... the script looses about 600ms of load time! Now my guess, is that its because its having to load sub-modules from within the requested ones. For example:

```
use WebService::Solr;
use WebService::Solr::Query;
use Want::View;
use JSON;
use POSIX;
```

On *Apache* with *mod_perl*, you can set the startup script so it "imports" the modules into memory (to make it faster). Is something similar possible with nginx and Perl? My live script it currently taking 1.1 seconds to process (of which 800-900ms of that is "waiting" for it to respond!!!!), so I really need to see about speeding it up.

**UPDATE:** I found this, but it doesn't seem to work:

http://search.cpan.org/~zzz/Nginx-Perl-1.2.9.7/src/http/modules/perl/Nginx.pm#DESCRIPTION

```
location ~ \.cgi$ {

    perl_inc     /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/;
    # perl_require WebService/Solr;

    ... rest

}
```

I get an error:

> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "perl_inc" in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.net:134

I'm wondering if its because I need to install the "Nginx" Perl module. When I try and install it via MCPAN though, I get a die:

> -lpthread -lcrypt -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz \
>   -Wl,-E -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status objs/Makefile:213: recipe for target
>   'objs/nginx-perl' failed make[1]: *** [objs/nginx-perl] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/root/.cpan/build/Nginx-Perl-1.2.9.7-dbUMQF' Makefile:9: recipe for
>   target 'build' failed make: *** [build] Error 2
>   ZZZ/Nginx-Perl-1.2.9.7.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK

Thanks!

Comment: I can't help with nginx specifics but if you don't find anything better you can still setup Apache and mod_perl and have nginx route Perl requests there.

Comment: @NickP - thanks. I was trying to avoid Apache as a proxy, as its one more thing to be running on the server :)

Comment: Forgive me if I am telling you anything you think is bleeding obvious, but "ld: cannot find -lperl" means you don't have libperl installed, so can you install it?

Comment: @Michael thanks for the reply. I just tried to install it, but doesn't seem to be a valid install? `apt-get install libperl` - gives: *E: Unable to locate package libperl* . My friend is suggesting that it needs nginx recompiled with some new flags ... although I'm not so sure

Comment: Ahh, you are using debian. Try 'apt-get install nginx-extras'. That should be dependant on a version of libperl (there may be no libperl, but there are versions of libperl, for example 'libperl5.14' on wheezy). It will probably pull in the perl module you want anyway.

Comment: @Michael - thanks, tried installing that (worked this time) ... but still didn't seem to wanna work. Think I may leave it to my mate  (a sysadmin), and see if he can get it going. Don't wanna break the server :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we finally got it going. Part of it I found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/247355/how-do-i-configure-nginxs-embedded-perl-to-use-perl-modules

We had to recompile it using the **--with-http_perl_module** and **--with-perl_modules_path** flags when configuring nginx. Then, the other thing that was confusing, was how you actually call it. Places I found as a reference, talk of:

```
perl_lib 
perl_require
```

I thought that was ok to put into the `location { }` part of a sites config file - but it turns out that needs to go into the main nginx.conf file, in the core:

```
http {
   perl_modules /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/;

   perl_require JSON.pm;
   perl_require POSIX.pm;

}
```

..block.

Doing it that way, actually seems to work (no compilation errors when rebooting nginx). I've still got some more testing to do, just to make sure it is indeed doing something - but from what I can see, this is now a working solution. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

**UPDATE:** I'm really not seeing any difference in load times :( My logic is that the perl_require loads the modules into memory, and this is then accessed quicker via the scripts (verses being loaded into the script itself). Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fix cpan problem by installing perl-dev or some similar package, containing C-level perl bindings. Than will be nginx-extras or, may be, rebuild your nginx from sources with perl support enabled.